# Make FancyBox in IFrame mode show close button

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, fancybox

I'm using FancyBox to display YouTube videos (using the YouTube embed link) with Fancy box in iframe mode. I want the Close button to show but setting the 'showCloseButton' didn't work. I google around a bit and apparently it won't show the close button in modal mode. I tried changing the 'modal' to false but that had no effect.

Here's the call I'm using now.

```
$('a[href*="youtube.com"]').fancybox({
                            'modal':false,
                            'showCloseButton' : true,
                            'type': 'iframe'
                             });
```

I'm using version 1.3.4. This problem seems to be the opposite problem from other StackOverflow users, they couldn't hide the close button. I've tried using other modes but couldn't get the video to show in any other modes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I only copied the .js and .css files into my js folder rather than copying the whole fancybox folder. So, it didn't have the close button image... Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Tried not putting at all the modal and showCloseButton :

```
$('a[href*="youtube.com"]').fancybox({'type': 'iframe'});
```

Comment: That's what I started with. Nope, no close button.

Comment: Mhhh so it would be a problem with the iframe Mode , have you tried removing it to ... just to be sure ? 

Could you give us a link or something to check it out online :)